# Beam window not triggering

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have the following code, which reads messages from pubsub. I expect to hit a breakpoint in the **TrackSpeed**() method when a window has been created, which never happens. Although I see log outputs from the **ExtractStationSpeedFn**()

Example log from there:

> INFORMATION: processing element
> DeviceData{deviceId='d2fa82a7-d70e-4057-8d4f-769c21815195', value=0.0,
> sensorId='b0f40aa4-696a-43be-bc3c-ffa4b36a8df5', formulaId='null',
> timeInNanoSeconds=1671533073470000000,
> receivedTimeInNanoSeconds=1671533073486702000}

What am I doing wrong?

Main method:

```
        pipeline.apply("Read PubSub messages",
                    PubsubIO.
                    readStrings().
                    fromSubscription("projects/seepex-cs/subscriptions/sensor-data-test_beam_6244029550622585075"))


            .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractStationSpeedFn()))
            .apply(
                    Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(30)))

            )
            .apply(new TrackSpeed())
            .apply("print", ParDo.of(new PrintElementFn()));
```

**ExtractStationSpeedFn**

```
static class ExtractStationSpeedFn extends DoFn<String, KV<String, DeviceData>> {
    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {

        String message = c.element();
        DeviceData data = new Gson().fromJson(message, DeviceData.class);

        String sourceId = data.getSensorId() != null ? data.getSensorId() : data.getFormulaId();

        KV<String, DeviceData> outputValue = KV.of(sourceId, data);
        c.output(outputValue);

        LOG.info("processing element {}", data);
    }
}
```

**TrackSpeed**

```
static class TrackSpeed extends PTransform<PCollection<KV<String, DeviceData>>, PCollection<Bucket>> {
    @Override
    public PCollection<Bucket> expand(PCollection<KV<String, DeviceData>> stationSpeed) {
        // Apply a GroupByKey transform to collect a list of all station
        // readings for a given route.
        PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<DeviceData>>> timeGroup = stationSpeed.apply(GroupByKey.create());

        PCollection<Bucket> stats = timeGroup.apply(ParDo.of(new GatherStats()));
        return stats;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `TrackSpeed()` method, are you trying to set a breakpoint in `TrackSpeed#expand(...)`?

Comment: Also, you might wanna checkout [`Combine.perKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine) to build your stats more efficiently.

Comment: .apply(new TrackSpeed()) im talking about this class. Additionally I just found out, that it works as indended when deployed to GCP dataflow but is not triggering locally in IntelliJ

Comment: This might be a misunderstanding ... `TrackSpeed#expand()` is called once **before** processing any data / windows to build the final DAG of your pipeline. If you want to debug how data is processed, make sure you set a breakpoint in the `DoFn` method annotated with `@ProcessElement`.

Comment: Okay, but inside of PCollection<Bucket> stats = timeGroup.apply(ParDo.of(new GatherStats())); there is a log.info which doesnt appear in the IDE. Is there a difference how windows are created locally vs in a deployed environment?